# Clear validation error messages after errors have been corrected

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a custom validator in asp.net that validates address client side, which works perfectly. Except, when i correct the error by filling up the text box, the error message doesn't disappear like it does for required field validators. The reason i use a custom validation is because i have separate boxes for street name, number, suburb etc and want to validate all of them at once.

Here is my JS:-

```
function ValidateAddress(src, args) {
var unit = document.getElementById('TextUnit');
var street = document.getElementById('TextStreet');
var sub = document.getElementById('TextSuburb');
var pc = document.getElementById('TextPC');

if (unit.value == "" || street.value == "" || sub.value == "" || pc.value == "")
{ args.IsValid = false; }

else { args.IsValid = true;}
}
```

Is there a way of making the error message disappear without using jquery? I solely have to use JS or HTML

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ValidateAddress function is called from somewhere else - probably a hook your validation framework has put on the form submit action or something similar. If your validation framework is handling re-validation of most of your controls after they have changed, it must be hooking the `onchange` event for those controls somehow. You will need to investigate how your validation framework is finding the controls it needs to watch for changes and update your address controls so that your validation framework detects and monitors them. Once your validation framework is handling `onchange` events for your address input controls the validation will be re-run and the error cleared when the user enters enough information.

Without more details about what validation framework you're using - or if you're using a homegrown validation framework, as seems likely - it'll be hard to give you a more specific answer.